# base.OnLoad(e) in a ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I might have misunderstood the meaning of `base.OnLoad(e);` My understanding was that this statement will call the OnLoad method of the base class of the class where it's called from. However, when I use the debugger to step through the code, I see different results.

```
public abstract class BaseUC : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
   protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   {
    base.OnLoad(e);

    SomeAbstractMethod();
   }
}
```

In the ascx.cs concrete class

```
public partial class MyUserControl : BaseUC
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //On Load logic
    }
}
```

I have a breakpoint on `base.OnLoad(e)`. When I press F11 (step into), the debugger takes me to `Page_Load` of MyUserControl, so the flow of control is:

```
BaseUC.OnLoad()
MyUserControl.Page_Load()
BaseUC.SomeAbstractMethod()
```

Can someone explain what's going on here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. BaseUC.Onload calls Control.OnLoad which triggers the Load event.
2. The Page_Load method works due to AutoEventWireUp=True and executes when the Load event executes.
3. BaseUC will then continue execution, calling SomeAbstractMethod.

Comment: "BaseUC.Onload calls Control.OnLoad which triggers the Load event." which line is making this happen?

Comment: I guess that's the part I don't understand. Why does base.OnLoad(e) call the Control.OnLoad (in this case the MyUserControl.Page_Load()
)?

Comment: @DotnetDude, every overriden implementation of OnLoad above you contains a call to base.OnLoad, until it reaches Control.OnLoad which triggers the Load event.

Comment: Is it safe to say that the base.OnLoad(e) raises an event and all the subscribers (MyUserControl.Page_Load()) to this event are notified and that's why the Page_Load is executed?

Comment: DotnetDude, that's both safe to say, and entirely correct. The topmost OnLoad will fire the Load event (it's a somewhat common theme to name methods that raise the event Xxx OnXxx).

Comment: And Page_Load() subscribing to the OnLoad() event is handled by the AutoEventWireUp? In theory can I have my own method subscribe to the OnLoad() event as well?

Comment: @DotnetDude, there are requirements for the naming of the automatically wired up methods (Page_Init, Page_Load). But you can attach any method (that fits the signature of the event) to Load, or even several methods if you want. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680878/what-does-autoeventwireup-page-property-mean where AutoEventWireUp have been discussed before.

Answer (score 5):

Page_Load and OnLoad are different things =)

Page_Load is a method that exists on the page which is called by the ASP.net runtime (thanks to the magic of AutoEventWireUp) OnLoad is the method that raises the Load event, so by putting code *before* the base.OnLoad(e) call you can cause code to execute prior to the event being raised, after it for code to run *after* the event is raised.

Take a look at [this blog entry](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2008/03/24/onload-vs-page-load-vs-load-event.aspx) from Infinities Loop entry on weblogs.asp.net about this for a bit of a broader explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Curiously, what are you expecting to see? I don't think you'll see it step in to **base.OnLoad(e)**, since your base class at that point is **System.Web.UI.UserControl**, and that is a system class, ... so you most likely don't have the source code for that to be able to step into it.

Comment: I expected:
BaseUC.OnLoad()
BaseUC.SomeAbstractMethod()
MyUserControl.Page_Load()

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the debug symbols loaded for System.Web?  F11 won't step into code you don't have loaded.

Comment: -1 definately not whats going on here... Other answers got the right idea

Comment: It's the most obvious part of the problem.  The OP is trying to step into a method in the BCL...

The other posters are absolutely correct about the call to Page_Load, but it's important to understand what the debugger is doing too.

Comment: Being able to step into System.Web would have shown the firing of the Load event and that Page_Load will react on it.