# How to make custom Dynamic Data field template combo box required

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, asp.net-dynamic-data

I have created a custom dynamic data field template to display a drop down list of states. The drop down appears no problem. But it is not displaying as 'Required'. Meaning if I leave it blank, I can still move on to the next page. Other fields on the page do validate correctly.

HTML of the field template

```
<%@ Control Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="State_Edit.ascx.vb"       Inherits="State_EditField" %>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="objectDataSourceState" runat="server" SelectMethod="GetAll" DataObjectTypeName="AsbestosEntities.lu_state" 
TypeName="AsbestosBusiness.StateController">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="ui-corner-all ui-widget input-text" AppendDataBoundItems="true" DataSourceID="objectDataSourceState" DataTextField="description" DataValueField="code">
<asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" CssClass="validator" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Static" Enabled="false" InitialValue="-1" />
<asp:DynamicValidator runat="server" ID="DynamicValidator1" CssClass="validator" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" Display="Static" />
```

Code Behind of the field template

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
Imports System.Web.DynamicData
Imports System.Web

Class State_EditField
Inherits FieldTemplateUserControl

Public Overrides ReadOnly Property DataControl As Control
    Get
        Return DropDownList1
    End Get
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If (DropDownList1.Items.Count = 0) Then
        If Mode = DataBoundControlMode.Insert OrElse Not Column.IsRequired Then
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(New ListItem("[Not Set]", ""))
        End If
        PopulateListControl(DropDownList1)
    End If
    SetUpValidator(RequiredFieldValidator1)
    SetUpValidator(DynamicValidator1)
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnDataBinding(ByVal e As EventArgs)
    MyBase.OnDataBinding(e)
    Dim selectedValueString As String = GetSelectedValueString()
    Dim item As ListItem = DropDownList1.Items.FindByValue(selectedValueString)
    If item IsNot Nothing Then
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = selectedValueString
    End If
End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub ExtractValues(ByVal dictionary As IOrderedDictionary)
    ' If it's an empty string, change it to null
    Dim value As String = DropDownList1.SelectedValue
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
        value = Nothing
    End If
    ExtractForeignKey(dictionary, value)
End Sub

End Class
```

The form view to display the field

```
<asp:FormView ID="FacilityInfo" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" DefaultMode="Insert"
                                DataKeyNames="facility_id">
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        <p>
            <h2>
                Enter the facility information:</h2>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="State" CssClass="detailheader"></asp:Label><br />
            <asp:DynamicControl ID="facility_state" runat="server" DataField="facility_state" HtmlEncode="true"
                                            Mode="Insert" CssClass="detailitem" />                                            
        </p>
    </InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
```

The model

```
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<MetadataType(GetType(facilityMetadata))> _
Public Class facility

    <Key()> _
    Public Property facility_id As Integer
    Public Property facility_state As String

End Class

Public Class facilityMetadata

    <UIHint("LongText")> _
    <DisplayName("Facility ID")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Facility ID is required")> _
    Public Property facility_id As Integer
    <UIHint("State")> _
    <DisplayName("State")> _
    <StringLength(2, ErrorMessage:="State cannot be more than 2 characters")> _
    <Required(ErrorMessage:="Facility state is required")> _
    <RegularExpression("^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage:="State can only contain letters.")> _
    Public Property facility_state As String

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is

```
<asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
```

that located inside your DropDownList.

Try use

```
<asp:ListItem Value="" Text=""></asp:ListItem>
```

instead of you are using.

**EDIT:**

I have just simulated your problem and I have found that you are using **AutoEventWireup** Page attribute of your custom field template

```
AutoEventWireup="false"
```

that prevent your Page_Load event to be automatically hooked to the page's Load event.

Change the value of this Page attribute to **true** (or remove one, because the default value is **true**) and try again.

For some information:

[What does AutoEventWireUp page property mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680878/what-does-autoeventwireup-page-property-mean)

Comment: Awesome. Thanks. Interestingly, I noticed that the Dynamic Field Templates created by visual studio do not have this explicitly set, its just not listed, meaning defaulting to true. But, when I create a user control, and turn it into a field template, AutoEventWireup is set to false. So, as an experiment, I left AutoEventWireup as false, and then explicitly handled the Page_Load event (adding Handles Me.Load) - page load is where the validators are set up - and that also worked.